# Diff tool that allows saving the compare markup

Tags: windows, diff

Is there a diff tool that allows saving of the compare markup?

To clarify, I would like to save the actual comparison of the two files that shows the differences to send to someone for review.

---

**EDIT**

Lots of good answers here. In my case I already had a copy of [Beyond Compare](http://scootersoftware.com) but didn't see the option. Thanks to John Saunders for pointing out the feature. It's "Session...Text Compare Report..." BTW.

My question was not specifically about Beyond Compare, so I am going to accept the answer that currently has the most up votes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is free and allows you to save the differences in various formats. It works well enough for me to not bother looking elsewhere, and I like the price.

There is also a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/winmerge_portable) if you can't, or don't want to, install it.

Comment: Perhaps a few details on how to do this could be useful. Am probably missing something but in version 2.14.0.0, the only way I could see to do this was via Tools - Generate Report (which only gives the option of saving as HTML).

Comment: @SteveChambers There is actually a way to obtain something more usable. For some reason, they call it "Patch". Click on "Tool", and then on "Generare Patch", and then you'll obtain a simple, usable diff of your two files in a text format.  Cf. my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48878453/2657549 (Using version 2.14.0.0 as well)

Comment: [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/downloads/source-code.php) is actually free as in "free speech". Its source code [is there](http://winmerge.org/downloads/source-code.php), and it is under [GNU General Public License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html). I think this is an important aspect.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the command line diff if you're using Unix, though it sounds like you're not.  Cygwin does bring a CLI diff, and Mac OS X ships with it.

```
$ diff <file> <other file> > mydiff.txt
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows. Updated the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Beyond Compare](http://scootersoftware.com/) does this.

Comment: I actually have a trial of Beyond Compare but didn't see the option at first. Just choose "Session...Text Compare Report..." and there it is. Beyond Compare FTW. :)

Answer (score 2):

I use the Scintilla Text Editor (SciTE) to open a diff file generated by command line or WinMerge, and then export the RTF, and it preserves color highlighting of differences. I use this method especially when emailing short patches for review in-house, and I use Outlook, for example.

The process I used just now as an example:

```
# diff -U 1000 a.txt b.txt > diff.txt
# scite diff.txt
### Edit-Copy as RTF
### Paste into Outlook
```

http://imagebin.ca/img/nBG25am.png

WinMerge provides this functionality through the Tools->Generate Patch menu item. I use the MSYS tools on windows, so that I run GNU diff a lot, but once you get the output, I would use SciTE if you need something like the above.

Answer (score 1):

[ExamDiff](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp) does a comparison which is shown in a window.  It can save a Unix-like formatted version of the differences.  Also, the file-to-file comparison version of the program is free!